# Unable to call describe_db_instances in aws lambda due to permission issue

Tags: python, aws-lambda, terraform, amazon-rds

I want to be able to run the following code:

```
rds = boto3.client("rds")
filters = [{
    "Name": "tag:Name",
    "Values": [f"*-{DB_SUFFIX}"]
}]
to_drop_dbs = rds.describe_db_instances(Filters=filters)
```

in order to select a list of db identifiers that has a common suffix.

I have encountered this error when I tried to run

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DescribeDBInstances
>   operation: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::888999792464:assumed-role/dev.lambda/list-all-dbs is not
>   authorized to perform: rds:DescribeDBInstances: ClientError

This is my policy statement for my lambda function in a terraform.

```
{   
    "Version": "2012-10-17",   
    "Statement": [  {
      "Effect": "Allow",
       "Action": [
         "rds:DescribeDBInstances"
       ],
       "Resource": [
         "arn:aws:rds:${var.region}:${local.account_id}:db:*"
      ]
     }]
 }
```

[image]

I tried the policy in the policy simulator. It fails as well, and there is no resource to specify.

My question:

How can I fix my policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the action you are describing in the Policy (namely rds:DescribeDBInstances) there can be no resource-level permissions.

That is, you can not limit the action to region or local account as you are trying to, the value of the resource in the policy must be "*".

```
{   
    "Version": "2012-10-17",   
    "Statement": [  {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "rds:DescribeDBInstances"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }]
}
```

When using the policy simulator, you can tell when a field value can be amended or not, as you will be able to edit that field in the simulation.

Below is a screen shot of what happens when you try and amend the resource value of rds:DescribeDBInstances and logs:GetLogEvents.

[image]

The resource simulation field can be amended for GetLogEvents, because the policy can be applied to individual log groups and streams.

But the resource simulation field can not be amended for DescribeDBInstances, because the policy can not be applied to individual or a subset of resources. It's all or nothing.

From [How Amazon RDS Works with IAM - Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/security_iam_service-with-iam.html#security_iam_service-with-iam-resource-based-policies)

> Some RDS API operations, such as those for creating resources, cannot
>   be performed on a specific resource. In those cases, you must use the
>   wildcard (*).